# Using fiddler to trace console app - OSX - Mono

Tags: mono, httpwebrequest, fiddler

I'm running Fiddler on OSX and it is happily tracing HTTP requests from chrome, dropbox and other processes on my machine but it does not show HTTP requests from a console app running on Mono.  The console app uses HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that you have to direct the app to use a proxy:

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
```